# How to upload an image in iframe using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a browse button after clicking on that button an iframe is opened. Choose file of type file is present on the iframe. I'm unable to click on that choose file.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Thread.sleep(2000);

 if (selenium.isTextPresent("Upload Your Own Image")) { 

     System.out.println("present");

  }
 else     
 {

System.out.println("No");

}

  Thread.sleep(1000);

WebElement element = 
             driver.findElement(By.id("image_form"));

              Actions action = new Actions(driver);

             action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

            element.click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("your browser button id")).click().sendKeys("C:\\Users\\pic.jpg");  - Did you try in this way?

Comment: i tried with driver.findElement(By.id("image_form")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\pic.jpg");

Comment: make sure your browse id is correct and picture path is correct.

Comment: Actullay when i use senkeys, at the bottom of the browser i can see the status as uploading(100%) but the image was not displayed in the iframe, at the same time if i upload image with wrong dimensions it should throw a msg but no msg is displayed but the status is displaying as uploading(100%)

Comment: is there any button on which you click then start upload? or it starts upload just after getting path?

Comment: here it is not the type of button. input id="file" type="file" onchange="$('#image_form').submit();$(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){$('#loading-gif').fadeIn('slow');});" name="file" style="margin:50px">    this is the code

Comment: Then first you will have to switch driver to get frame : driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(0);
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   if (selenium.isTextPresent("Upload Your Own Image")) {
  System.out.println("present");
 }else {
  System.out.println("No");
 }
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement element = 
        driver.findElement(By.id("image_form"));
         Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
       element.click();....This is my code

Comment: Why you using sleep method? I think you should use Wait method first.

Comment: no if i use wait command i;m gettinng error

Comment: Strange..What error you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this exception java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to that iframe before clicking

`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));`

applicable if there is only one iframe in a page (else point the element By. some other selector)

and then use your code.

So.

`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));`

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("image_form"));`

`Actions action = new Actions(driver);`

`action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();`

`element.click();`

Answer (score -1):

This is my code

driver.switchTo().frame(0);

```
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  if (selenium.isTextPresent("Upload Your Own Image")) {
    System.out.println("present");
}else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement element = 
                 driver.findElement(By.id("image_form"));
                  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                 action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
                element.click();
```

Comment: Then you should post with question. Not as answer. Please update your question with this code.

Comment: so I updated my code, if you know the answer could u please tell me the correct way